# How to fix "XmlFileNotFound" in spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am setting up the Path but though it is showing "File not Found"

This is what I am trying

```
ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("employeeBean.xml");
        Employee e1 = context.getBean("emp1",Employee.class);
        Employee e2 = context.getBean("emp2",Employee.class);
```

it shows this Error

> parsing XML document from file
>   [C:\Users\Trigno\eclipse-workspace\Edureka\employeeBean.xml]; nested
>   exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: employeeBean.xml (The
>   system cannot find the file specified)

Answer (score 0):

You should to use `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/employeeBean.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to load the configuration.
1. You either need to use ClassPathXmlApplicationContext if file is present inside src/main/resource
2. You can use FileSystemXmlApplicationContext, but you need to move the file to the root directory of project.